# pdflatex renders files differently from a strings -- example provided

Tags: pdftex, circuitikz, minimal

I am running pdftex from command line and the images are getting clipped.  When I run the same commands from a saved tex file, no clipping occurs. I have attached the commands and rendered outputs also available (if you bump up my reputation points I can upload them). I do not see any unusual differences in the log files.

This seems like a bug and pdftex's tracking system would not let me register to file a bug (http://foundry.supelec.fr/gf/project/pdftex/).

Can some please confirm this as bug, recommend how I can report it, and perhaps provide a workaround.  I am trying to render a circuitikz via commandline.

```
:: PDF from Files
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -jobname circuit_file circuit.tex circuit.pdf

:: PDF from String   
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -jobname circuit_string \documentclass[class=minimal,border=4pt]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{circuitikz} \usepackage{siunitx} \pagestyle{empty} \begin{document} \begin{circuitikz}[european]\draw(0,0) to [V, v=$V_1$, i_=$I_1$] (0,2)to [R, l^=${R_1}$] (2,2)to [R, l^=${R_2}$, v^<=$V_2$] (2,0) -- (0,0); \end{circuitikz} \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I get the same result provided I remove `class=minimal`, which is wrong.

Comment: You should quote the string to protect it from changes by the OS. Use double quotes on MS Windows and single quotes on Linux/Unix and probably Mac OS X. Also, as author of `standalone` I really agree with @egreg here about not using the `minimal` "class". See also [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/2975).

Answer (score 4):

As Martin suggested, putting quotes around the latex string solved the clipping problem.

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -jobname circuit_string "\documentclass[border=4pt]{article} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{circuitikz} \usepackage{siunitx} \pagestyle{empty} \begin{document} \begin{circuitikz}[european]\draw(0,0) to [V, v=$V_1$, i_=$I_1$] (0,2)to [R, l^=${R_1}$] (2,2)to [R, l^=${R_2}$, v^<=$V_2$] (2,0) -- (0,0); \end{circuitikz} \end{document}"
```

Comment: Ok, I recently switched from Miktex on Windows to texlive on Linux.  I type the same command above and now I get an error in Linxux:
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@let@token ...{ \pgf@circ@finallabel {voltage/} }

<*> ...european]\draw(0,0) to [V, v=$, i_=$] (0,2)
                                                  to [R, l^=$] (2,2)to [R, l...
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on circuit_string.log.

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double.  Some of your $ characters are being interpreted as the start of shell variables.